# Amazon SSH connection to private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I need form my Amazon cluster connect by ssh from one machine to another. I try to add everything in the security group to allow access from the machine that make the call adding his Private and Public IP with the 22 port. But still I just can connect to that machine from the external IP, and what I need is make the connection using the private IP.

Any suggestion? I´m missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things needed to make this happen.

1. Add access to the security group of the other machine and not ip address (on port 22). If both are in the same security group, then the group needs to allow access to itself. This is not done by default.
2. Connect using the public DNS of the public IP address. This will resolve correctly to the private IP address within ec2.

Comment: Both machines are not in the same security group, but I already add it in the default security group of the new machine all traffic allowed for 0.0.0.0

Comment: About use the public DNS no chance, all this problems comes because I´m using a Jenkins plugins to create ec2 instance, but he is trying to connect using thw private IP because Amazon detect that both machines are in the same cluster.

Comment: If I connect using the external IP or the public DNS the ssh works perfectly. What I need to know if it is possible make a ssh connection to another machine in the same cluster using the Private IP